# replace row sqlalchemy with new version

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm taking json data from a remote server. Each entry contains a modified date. If the entry exists in my local database I'd like to replace the current local entry with the new one.

I'm using sqlalchemy (latest version) and I can add a new instance just fine. I am assuming I will be able to query to detect whether I need to replace the local version or not (or just run an insert). My question is whether it is better to do a `delete` call then a `add` call, or whether there is a more efficient approach. To complicate matters, the change may have been triggered not by the primary object, but by an object it points to. In other words this object holds objects that are in other tables - one-to-many relationship, and one of those objects may have changed or been deleted.

Finally, the data that I am receiving via json only contains non-null fields (not all fields). All non-specified fields should be null/default after updating the row.

Comment: Why are you doing this with sqlalchemy instead of some database synchronization tool?

Comment: I'm consuming data from a REST API (not mine) and implementing a local database to work with the consumed data. From your question I gather that a database synchronization tool might be more appropriate if I controlled both sides?